# How to find unrelated types (in a unidirectional directed graph)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to find nodes of a certain category that are not related to nodes of another category.
For example, if nodes are PEOPLE and relationships are KNOWS, say I want to find all People from England that don't know anyone from France.

I've tried something like this:

```
match(a:People {Country: "England"})
match(b:People {Country: "France"})
where NOT (a)-[:REFERENCES]->(b)
RETURN count(a)
```

However, this is (I believe) returning a cartesian product, as the number returned is many times greater than the number of People in the DB.

How should I rewrite the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it ...

```
MATCH (pe:People {country: "England"})
WHERE NOT (pe)-[:REFERENCES]->(:People {country: "France"})
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT pe);
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom